# How to receive info from 2 tables from the same database in the same page?

Tags: php, jquery, database

I have 1 big form that will receive information from 2 different tables (table1 and table2) in the same database.

All info will be placed in the same form where you can save it all to a new table.

My issue is when some of the row in both table (table1 and table2) have the same name how do I call the info from the correct table. So fare I have:

1.
The URL that will call the info looks like:

```
….info.php?id=320&folder=ras
```

2.
The query:

```
if(!$_POST["submit"])
{
//INFO FORM TABLE 1
$query = mysql_query("select country, state, name, dob from table1 where id = '".$_GET["id"]."' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$country = $row[0];
$state = $row[1];
$name = $row[2];
$dob = $row[3];

//INFO FORM TABLE 2
$query = mysql_query("select country, state, name, dob from table2 where folder = '".$_GET["folder"]."' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$country = $row[0];
$state = $row[1];
$name = $row[2];
$dob = $row[3];
```

3.
The code on the website:

```
From table 1: //1 <?=$country?> //2 <?=$state?> //3 <?=$name?> //4 <?=$dob?> 
From table 2: //1 <?=$country?> //2 <?=$state?> //3 <?=$name?> //4 <?=$dob?>
```

Im not sure how to do this, but I think that I need to change one of the query to something like:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("select country, state, name, dob from table2 where folder = '".$_GET["folder"]."' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
$country = $row[0];
$state = $row[1];
$name = $row[2];
$dob = $row[3];
```

But if  I do that what code should I use for call the info in table2. `<?=$2”country”?>` don’t work.

Please advice.

Comment: Change all variables: `$query` to `$query2`, `$row` to `$row2` and so on...

Comment: Do you just want the data no matter where it comes from? Then just `JOIN` the tables and use one query

Comment: off the record,try changing to PDO or Mysqlli instead of mysql

Comment: Why not using a UNION?

Comment: @kingkero @Pedro I'm not familiar with using `JOIN` or `UNNION` how do I use that?

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dde3/3) e.g., you could then iterate over the result (as it is 2 rows) and use the same template again. This would remove redundancy in your code

Answer (score 1):

You need something like (for a quick solution):

```
    //INFO FORM TABLE 1
    $query = mysql_query("select country, state, name, dob from table1 where id = '".$_GET["id"]."' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $country = $row[0];
    $state = $row[1];
    $name = $row[2];
    $dob = $row[3];

    //INFO FORM TABLE 2
    $query2 = mysql_query("select country, state, name, dob from table2 where folder = '".$_GET["folder"]."' ");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
    $country2 = $row2[0];
    $state2 = $row2[1];
    $name2 = $row2[2];
    $dob2 = $row2[3];
```

Just for future reference, if you set a value to same variable twice, PHP will always give you result for later assignment.

Comment: If I change the codes as you suggest how do I call it fro the website. I mean normally I would use: `<?=$country?>` but what to use when needs to get info from table2? Please advice :)

Comment: For any table2 result, use the second variable, for eg. `$country2`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer me. If I change it to: `    //INFO FORM TABLE 2
    $query2 = mysql_query("select country, state, name, dob from table2 where folder = '".$_GET["folder"]."' ");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
    $country2 = $row2[0];
    $state2 = $row2[1];
    $name2 = $row2[2];
    $dob2 = $row2[3];` and secound variable to `<?=$country2?>` it does not Work. Can you see what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you name it different?
Like:

```
$country_table1 = $row[0];
$state_table1 = $row[1];
$name_table1 = $row[2];
$dob_table1 = $row[3];
```

and

```
$country_table2 = $row[0];
$state_table2 = $row[1];
$name_table2 = $row[2];
$dob_table2 = $row[3];
```

Can you provide your HTML code ?

Comment: codes are in table and forms on the page so not ease to show here. Anyway what is important is how to call the info from table2.